# JavaFX, Apache NetBeans 10, no class visible

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-10

I want to create a cool app in `JavaFX`. When I installed `NetBeans IDE` and did all stuff around, I'm not able to run project, because there is no visible (available Java class).

1. Create project:

[image]

2. Make sure that `Create application class` check box is selected.

[image]

3. Try to run my project, but there is no Java class.
   [image]

Can you help me please guys?
Is there any problem with IDE or with the code?

**Mycoolproject.java -> Right Click -> RUn file:**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$412(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at mycoolproject.Mycoolproject.start(Mycoolproject.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$419(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$399(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$397(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$398(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$203(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application mycoolproject.Mycoolproject
/...path..../mycoolproject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1340: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/...path..../mycoolproject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:981: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: right click on Mycoolproject.java and run ?

Comment: right click on Mycoolproject.java > Run As > Java Application

Comment: added log in topic